# Limit Dates available for selection and limit enteries displayed by those dates

Tags: list, filter, date-time

I am creating a small `timereporting` list and would like to have the user select from a list of limited dates. The dates should be all the date for beginning of the week (i.e. `05/04/2015, 05/11/2015, 05/18/2015`) I would like the selection to be for the `current month +one week` of the prior month and `+two weeks of the future month`. In addition I would like to limit thier view of thier entries in the list to the same parameters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it for filtering list or while creating new items?

Comment: The dates should be limited for while creating new items.

Comment: I have solved for limiting users view of thier entries in the list to current month +one week of the prior month and +two weeks of the future month.

Comment: I still need help with when they are creating the entries to limit the dates.

Comment: Try manipulating this using JavaScript